# Trigger inserts more rows than it should

Tags: t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Suppose I have a table MyTab:

```
MyTab(ID, Col1, Col2, Col3,...)
```

Then I created a delete trigger like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_MyTab_Delete]
ON [dbo].[MyTab]
For DELETE AS
begin

  INSERT INTO dbo.DeleteHistory(...)
  SELECT * FROM deleted d;

end
```

This works fine for single row data delete. But it will not work for batch delete like

```
delete from MyTab where ...
```

If above delete delete 10 rows from `MyTab`, trigger will insert 10*10 = 100 rows into `DeleteHistory`.

How to resolve this issue to make this trigger works fine for both single row and more than one row delete?

Comment: The trigger actually already looks like it should handle multiple-row deletes just fine. Are you sure this is exactly what your trigger looks like? If it is different, we can't fix what we can't see.

Comment: I suspect your actual trigger says `INSERT ... SELECT d.* FROM deleted d, deleted` or `FROM deleted d, MyTab WHERE d.key = MyTab.key`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work properly. See this SQL fiddle for a demonstration:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/90f47/3/2

You have something else fishy going on. Maybe you haven't shown the actual trigger code, maybe you have other triggers running or something else... hard to guess.